# python development best practice: pip or PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pythonpath

We are developing a Python package and my question is about a specific development best practice. There are two workflows present in the team:

### Workflow 1

1. change the code
2. install the package with `pip install`
3. test and debug

### Workflow 2

1. set the `PYTHONPATH` to the package source
2. change the code
3. test and debug

One of my team mates keeps telling me that Workflow 2 is bad habit. Instead I should follow Workflow 1 and define a hook that automatically runs `pip uninstall`/`install`. He has a very strong opinion about this, but I really do not see the point of not using `PYTHONPATH`.

Hence, I'd like to listen to your thoughts on the two workflows. Are there any pros/cons related to both workflows?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for ProgrammersSE. That said, I think the best workflow is to create a `setup.py` and use `python setup.py develop` to install the package, which will ensure that any edits you make are reflected when the package is imported.